# Make a tag based survey

Tags: discussion, feature-request, open-source-advertising

Is it possible on Stack Overflow to publish/distribute a survey for a specific tag?

For example, for an open source project, to get to know how it is used and what would be the best way to continue developing on the project?

For example like this: http://benedikteg.typeform.com/to/NHWs0o

This would be nice for knowing, how to spent time/money on such a project.

Comment: You're correct, i removed it :) Cause of the down-votes would some one explain the problem with the question? Would be happy to improve it :)!

Comment: I stopped that survey since it insists to continue after I answered _No_ for _"Do you use IronPython?*"_.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I try to fix this!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in the "Basic Version" i'm using logic elements for canceling are not possible. I will try to buy a version tomorrow to make this possible. Currently i added some information to make it clearer to everyone. Thank you for that hint!

Comment: The downvotes simply show disagreement for needing such feature,

Comment: This "feature" might benefit *you* as the developer of the product, but how does it benefit *us* as the general population of Stack Overflow users? What's the redeeming value that justifies the team giving you the right to push out unsolicited crap like this to us?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that such kind of surveys as you mentioned would give any benefit to the Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange site.

That's merely like a question ...

> 1. Do you use IronPython?
> 2. Where do you use IronPython?
> 3. What do you use IronPython for?
> 4. Would you support the project by donating to hire some  developer to work constantly on IronPython to be more Python compatible and get rid of bugs very fast?
>
> Thank you for your answers. The results will be public as soon as the survey ends. Thank you all a lot! If you want, you can let some information right here.

... which I'd immediately vote to close as off-topic. Either as *too broad* or *primarily opinion based*.

How should pulling personal preferences and opinions be helpful for the intended Q&A format of the SE sites?

---

> This would be nice for knowing, how to spent time/money on such a project.

Just research on such projects activities, and judge if it's worth following, using or even participating.

Having a small community existing on Stack Overflow because of a tag might anyways not be relevant for the significance of the potential responses you get.

Comment: There *are* yearly surveys which essentially ask those questions, though. I don't necessarily think we should have tag-based surveys, but just because they're off-topic as a question on SO, doesn't mean they don't belong (otherwise we should ditch the yearly survey, too).